# Mysql sum column from multiple table in the same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have 18 table in mysql.

All of tables have a column Result (ex a.result, b.result etc..)
I need to select the result of 18 table and sum together for all of the id.

`d.id 1 = a.result + b.result + c.result` (of id 1 in all of the table)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL` to get all value from all 18 tables. Then use `SUM` function.

**Query**

```
SELECT SUM(t.result) FROM(
    SELECT result FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT result FROM table_2
    UNION ALL
    ...........................
    ...........................
    SELECT result FROM table_18
)t;
```

If you want the `result` column value for specific id's from the table. Then, use `WHERE`.

Comment: @bassrek : Actually the question is not that clear. I think result column value for the id = 1 from all columns. Then, it would be possible with `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @Ulas - looks like you saw my comment before I deleted it.  I noticed your last line about the `WHERE` clause after I posted my note, so I deleted :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but something like this would work

```
SELECT a.result + b.result + c.result -- (All the way to r.result...)
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
  ON a.ID = b.ID
INNER JOIN TableC c
  ON b.ID = c.ID
-- (All the way to TableR ...)
```

You might want to consider using `OUTER JOINS` unless you're absolutely certain that the ID will always exist in all tables.